# Websphere MQ C++ Multi-threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, ibm-mq

I'm new with **Websphere MQ V7 C++**. I'm thinking of creating *multi-threaded application* to get and to respond in the message on the queue. Can you guys give me an example regarding this multi-threaded approach using pthread library? I don't have any idea how to create one.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would not recommend using the C++ api - it has been stabilized and is not being extended for the newer functionality. Use C calls from a C++ app instead

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.doc%2Fzd00030_.htm
"As of WebSphere MQ Version 7.0, enhancements to the WebSphere MQ programming interfaces will not be applied to the C++ classes."

In terms of the multithreaded approach, it should be no different to any normal threaded program... If you dont use shared hconns then a hconn is only valid for the thread it was created on, and if you do use shared hconns I wouldn't try sharing them across threads simultaneously (calls will usually block depending on sharing options).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Regarding multithreaded MQ C API use, is there any way to abort a waiting MQGET (when terminating the app, for example)? Both MQDISC and MQCLOSE seem to block if there is an MQGET in progress.

Comment: Each hconn can only have one API underway at any point in time. So you would have a few options... have 2 connections, and in the second wake the mqget up (dummy message, make queue get inhibited) or alternatively use the newer MQCB so rather than sitting in an MQGET, you get called when a message is available. If you have to do it via a single connection, consider MQGET/wait and if you timeout, check to see if you should abort, and if not, go back into the wait.

Answer (score 0):

In other case, if you make program who get mesage do something and put mesagge in response, and no do another complex logic. You can instantiate n times of that program, if you not have suficient experience with P-trhead.